# What is it called when someone pays more for a service for personal gain?

Tags: money

Let's say someone works for a company. They decide to hire a friend to do a service for said company and pay their friend way above market price for said service at the expense of the company. What would that be called if there is a word for it.

Apparently I need to supply context. I'm writing a bit of a short story and would like to sum up this action in one word if possible. The character gets caught doing this action and a fellow worker will confront them about it in a scene.

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed.  The OP was asking for a particular term, reasonably well specified, with no reason why it should be context-dependent.

Comment: It helps to follow [the link](/tags/single-word-requests/info), which says “INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.”  So, would it be “You floogled!” (verb), “that contract was a floogle!” (noun), “that contract was very floogly” (adjective), or something else?  ...  I can’t think of a *single* word that encompasses the entire idea;  for a noun, “fraud”, “embezzlement”, “money-laundering” and “kickback” may be good starting points.  (Look them up in a thesaurus and see what you get.)